# No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxItemTemplet'

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have created one layout but while debugging it shows this error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxItemTemplet'" with package name

```
 <Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemSource Kittens"
    local:MvxItemTemplet="@layout/item_kitten" />
```

Comment: You wrote it wrong. Try with `MvxItemTemplate` instead of Templet